# pop-up effect similar to dropDownMenuButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I hope I can make this kind of pop-up effect similar to dropDownMenuButton. Is there any plugin or example that can be used for reference or help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a floating window i would suggest using a dialog.

To use a dialog you use a function and provide it with a context

This example should show a rounded corned white dialog with "YAY!" in the middle of it.

You close the dialog calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()` , and You could also use the align widget combined with padding to make it appear to the bottom, top, left, and right.

Touching on the backdrop of the dialog will also dismiss it.

```
void _showDialog(context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return my custom widgets
        return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 250.0,
                height: 250.0,
                child: Material( //Use material to use FlatButton, IconButton, InkWell, etc.
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('YAY!')
                    )));
      },
    );
  }
```

Feel free to experiment.

Comment: Yes, I have considered dialog, but dialog has no animation effect. The effect is not very good. Do you have other better recommendations? Thank you.